# Substring and gsub in R

Tags: r, substring, gsub

I have strings formatted like `\t\tloc: 'Silver Spring, MD',` that I extracted from a website and want to retrieve just the city name and state abbreviations, e.g. `Silver Spring, MD`. I was thinking about doing a combination of `gsub` and `substr` but the city name could change based on other data so it wouldn't make sense to give `substr` a start and end index. Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
# Would like to extract the string "Silver Spring, MD"
# What I tried:
ldata <- "\t\tloc: 'Silver Spring, MD',"
dt<- gsub(".*: ", "",ldata)
# Produces: 'Silver Spring, MD',"
```

The string however always appears in the same way, with the city name in the 'ABCDE, FG' part of the string segment. I'm new to R so if there's a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dt<-sub(".*'(.*)'.*","\\1",ldata)
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly. Though I'm trying to understand it and can't quite figure out what '(.*)' is read as by R. Does that mean anything encapsulated within ' ' ?

Comment: The first instance of `.*` means anything until it hits first `'`, `'(.*)'` means "find single quoted sequence and remember (the `( )` does that) what's inside", then continue with `grep`. What is remembered is kept with the `\\1` command, the rest is dumped. I'm sure, there is a better and more concise explanation than that, tho :)

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov No, that was perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another option without using the capture group is

```
gsub("^[^']+'|',$", '', ldata)
#[1] "Silver Spring, MD"
```